# Почему нельзя объявить объект структуры в структуре

Tags: c++

```
struct Node {

    int data;
    struct Node left;
    struct Node right;
};
```

`Field has incomplete type 'struct Node'`

Почему нельзя так сделать?

Comment: Потому что память конечна.

Comment: Потому что для объявления структуры компилятор должен заранее знать размер всей полей структуры. В таких случаях члены left и right объявляются указателями, так как размер указателя известен заранее, и не зависит от указуемого типа (кроме очень редких исключений, с которыми вы не встретитесь)

Comment: @vadyanysh, Когда вы найдете во вселенной объект, который состоит из такого же объекта и еще из чего то, тогда  снова задайте этот вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Представим ситуацию, что такое возможно, тогда получим, что при создании экземпляра класса не хватит никакой оперативной памяти, ибо такой объект по сути бесконечен + невозможно закончить его.

Вам необходимо заменить типы left и right с Node на Node* и работать уже так.